# set of numbers created by arithmetic operations on a set

Tags: arithmetic

I recently went to a math circle where we discussed arithmetic operations on a set. The main goal was to find the set of numbers that could be made by using addition, parentheses, subtraction, and multiplication on the set {${1,2,3,4}$}. The conductor of the math circle said that he was inspired by a particular paper he read. I was quite interested in the topic. Does anyone have any idea what paper he may be talking about, or any papers similar to the above topic?

Comment: Is using the same number more than once allowed? (I presume not.)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel You are correct.

Comment: aka what is the arithmetic closure of a given set.